# Update property in master table if property in child table is equal to

Tags: boolean, devexpress, xaf

I have 2 tables. Table A (Master) and Table B (Child) developed in DevExpress XAF.
I need to update a single property in Table A (Field End) if a record in Table B meets this requirements:

- Field Status = "Ended", where Status it's an Enum field.

So, in Table A, the field End is a bool property.

Here's what I write so far, but no luck...

In table B code page:

```js
private bool _end;
        public bool End
        {
            get
            {
                return _end;
            }
            set
            {
                bool result;
                
                TableB.Status c = new TableB.Status();
                if (c == TableB.Status.Ended)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                }

                SetPropertyValue<bool>("StatusField", ref _end, result);
            }
        }
```

I run my project, change the field in table B to "Ended", save the record but no changes in field End in table A.

Any ideias?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing, as you say your master table "A" (in XAF terms that would be a Business Object or BO) has a property called "End", yet the the code you posted which appears to define that property you say is for the child "B".

Assuming you meant to say that the code is for BO "A", then that's approaching the problem from the wrong end - the code posted would only have an effect when A.End is assigned a value, but you want to set the value when B.Status is set to "Ended", so you need to write some code into the "Ended" property of B.

You also don't state what field relates the two BOs, so I'm going to assume for this example that the child B has a property called "Master", of type A. I also assume that the "Status" enum is defined in B.

In which case you want something like this, in the code for B:

```
    private Status _status;
    public Status StatusField {

        get { return _status; }
        set {
            if (value == Status.Ended && Master != null) {
                Master.End = true;
            }
            SetPropertyValue("StatusField", ref _status, value);
        }
    }
```